# Programmatically keep Windows pointer visible

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, winapi

When you disconnect a physical mouse from Windows, the mouse pointer now disappears. I forget which version of Windows this started with, but it wasn't always like this. Is there any way to programmatically keep the mouse pointer visible all the time in all apps as if a physical mouse is connected? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/solved-mouse-pointer-cursor-disappears-on-windows-10.html#Way5

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with a SteelSeries Sensei Ten mouse on Windows 10 using wagtail.ani as the normal mouse pointer. Have you tried with a different mouse? Or maybe with a different cursor?

Comment: @AndrewMorton This only happens when no physical mouse is plugged into the computer

Comment: @HansPassant Those solutions are only if the pointer isn't showing when you already have a mouse plugged in

Comment: @Ray Do you mean when you start the computer with no physical mouse plugged in, or when you unplug a physical mouse from a running computer? (I tried the latter.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton When I start with no mouse plugged in